# Preenchimento automatico dos campos

Tags: django, python-2.7

Estou desenvolvendo uma [aplicação](https://github.com/Sniickers/Two) com Django (1.6.2) e Python 2.7 para aprendizado, a aplicação realiza cadastros, pesquisas e edições no DB, em um dos cadastros que eu realizo eu gostaria de aplicar uma função de preenchimento automático de outros campos do formulário, igual a alguns sites em que você digita o seu CPF ou CEP e os campos de nome e endereços são preenchidos automaticamente ao clicar fora do campo preenchido.

Só que no caso os campos seriam preenchidos de acordo com o código (primary key) dos itens ja cadastrados no meu Database.

Como ficaria para eu implementar essa função na minha aplicação?!

Até agora não tenho usado nada além de Django, Python e o Bootstrap para as templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisará utilizar JQuery para implementar essa funcionalidade.

Você está fazendo isso no django admin ou em uma aplicação fora do admin?

Caso seja no admin, dê uma olhada nesta [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions)

Comment: Estou fazendo fora do admin!

Comment: Então faça via JQuery/Ajax. Para CEP procure uma base de dados do correio ou veja sobre o google maps API de pesquisa. Para CPF, você terá que implementar a pesquisa em sua view.